Task :buildSrc:compilePluginsBlocks FAILED for no apparent reason
This was building fine then started to fail without any change to buildSrc
I have not idea what is happening. Retrying with clean and --rerun-tasks doesn't help.
$ ./gradlew clean check --rerun-tasks
> Task :buildSrc:compilePluginsBlocks FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':buildSrc:compilePluginsBlocks'.
> 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.psi.PsiElement org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.SharedImplUtil.lass(org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.lang.ASTNode)'


EDIT: It seems that running git clean -fdx on the repo fixes the issue.
Apparently the issue above is preventing even the clean task from running, so gradle is stuck in bad state.
What happened here?
Here is the stacktrace:
[ ... al lot of bytecode or something?]
(Lorg/jetbrains/kotlin/psi/stubs/KotlinClassOrObjectStub<+Lorg/jetbrains/kotlin/psi/KtClassOrObject;>;Lorg/jetbrains/kotlin/com/intellij/psi/stubs/IStubElementType<**>;)Veæÿeæÿeæÿeæÿeæÿeæÿeæÿ?eæÿeæÿeæÿeæÿeæÿe50C}¤{?WA()
0Ev[}¤{q]Method org/jetbrains/kotlin/com/intellij/psi/StubBasedPsiElement.getContainingFile()Lorg/jetbrains/kotlin/com/intellij/psi/PsiFile; is abstractUãԗMethod org/jetbrains/kotlin/com/intellij/psi/StubBasedPsiElement.acceptChildren(Lorg/jetbrains/kotlin/com/intellij/psi/PsiElementVisitor;)V is abstractuàVß}¤{¥¨Method org/jetbrains/kotlin/com/intellij/psi/StubBasedPsiElement.getCopyableUserData(Lorg/jetbrains/kotlin/com/intellij/openapi/util/Key;)Ljava/lang/Object; is abstractu¬ß}¤{%`©Method org/jetbrains/kotlin/com/intellij/psi/StubBasedPsiElement.putCopyableUserData(Lorg/jetbrains/kotlin/com/intellij/openapi/util/Key;Ljava/lang/Object;)V is abstractåÓ@]Method org/jetbrains/kotlin/com/intellij/psi/StubBasedPsiElement.textContains(C)Z is abstractõ▒¥{ôäfMethod org/jetbrains/kotlin/com/intellij/psi/StubBasedPsiElement.getStartOffsetInParent()I is abstractU04ß}¤{{Method org/jetbrains/kotlin/com/intellij/psi/StubBasedPsiElement.getTextRange()Lorg/jetbrains/kotlin/com/intellij/openapi/util/TextRange; is abstractå°Ú}¤{(]Method org/jetbrains/kotlin/com/intellij/psi/StubBasedPsiElement.getTextOffset()I is abstractE ©Ù}¤{kMethod org/jetbrains/kotlin/com/intellij/psi/StubBasedPsiElement.findElementAt(I)Lorg/jetbrains/kotlin/com/intellij/psi/PsiElement; is abstractU?7~¤{Ò͓Method org/jetbrains/kotlin/com/intellij/psi/StubBasedPsiElement.findReferenceAt(I)Lorg/jetbrains/kotlin/com/intellij/psi/PsiReference; is abstractå@mÁ|¤{+`Method org/jetbrains/kotlin/com/intellij/psi/StubBasedPsiElement.textToCharArray()[C is abstractU0~¤{1ãMethod org/jetbrains/kotlin/com/intellij/psi/StubBasedPsiElement.getNavigationElement()Lorg/jetbrains/kotlin/com/intellij/psi/PsiElement; is abstractUîÎ}¤{§֓Method org/jetbrains/kotlin/com/intellij/psi/StubBasedPsiElement.getOriginalElement()Lorg/jetbrains/kotlin/com/intellij/psi/PsiElement; is abstract°uX~¤{õsMethod org/jetbrains/kotlin/com/intellij/psi/StubBasedPsiElement.textMatches(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)Z is abstractEp&ü}¤{9#Method org/jetbrains/kotlin/com/intellij/psi/StubBasedPsiElement.textMatches(Lorg/jetbrains/kotlin/com/intellij/psi/PsiElement;)Z is abstractÕ 6Ò}¤{¼ØMethod org/jetbrains/kotlin/psi/KtAnnotated.addAfter(Lorg/jetbrains/kotlin/com/intellij/psi/PsiElement;Lorg/jetbrains/kotlin/com/intellij/psi/PsiElement;)Lorg/jetbrains/kotlin/com/intellij/psi/PsiElement; is abstractbstract(ASTDelegatePsiElement.java:114)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.psiUtil.PsiUtilsKt$siblings$1$iterator$1.next(psiUtils.kt:57)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.psiUtil.PsiUtilsKt$siblings$1$iterator$1.next(psiUtils.kt:49)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtQualifiedExpression.getExpression(KtQualifiedExpression.kt:47)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtQualifiedExpression.getReceiverExpression(KtQualifiedExpression.kt:29)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtDotQualifiedExpression.getReceiverExpression(KtDotQualifiedExpression.kt:45)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtPackageDirective.getPackageNames(KtPackageDirective.java:67)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtPackageDirective.getQualifiedNameOf(KtPackageDirective.java:160)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtPackageDirective.getQualifiedName(KtPackageDirective.java:151)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtPackageDirective.getFqName(KtPackageDirective.java:112)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtFile.getPackageFqNameByTree(KtFile.kt:102)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtFile.getPackageFqName(KtFile.kt:90)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.UtilsKt$checkKotlinPackageUsageForPsi$1.invoke(utils.kt:77)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.UtilsKt$checkKotlinPackageUsageForPsi$1.invoke(utils.kt:75)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.UtilsKt.checkKotlinPackageUsage(utils.kt:55)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.UtilsKt.checkKotlinPackageUsageForPsi(utils.kt:75)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.UtilsKt.checkKotlinPackageUsageForPsi$default(utils.kt:70)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileBunchOfSources(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:136)
        at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.support.KotlinCompilerKt.compileKotlinScriptModuleTo(KotlinCompiler.kt:189)
        at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.support.KotlinCompilerKt.compileKotlinScriptModuleTo(KotlinCompiler.kt:101)
        at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.plugins.precompiled.tasks.CompilePrecompiledScriptPluginPlugins.compile(CompilePrecompiledScriptPluginPlugins.kt:107)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:125)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:29)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$3.run(TaskExecution.java:244)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:166)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeAction(TaskExecution.java:229)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeActions(TaskExecution.java:212)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(TaskExecution.java:195)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.execute(TaskExecution.java:162)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.executeInternal(ExecuteStep.java:105)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.access$000(ExecuteStep.java:44)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:56)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:209)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:166)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:56)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:44)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:42)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:55)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.PreCreateOutputParentsStep.execute(PreCreateOutputParentsStep.java:50)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.PreCreateOutputParentsStep.execute(PreCreateOutputParentsStep.java:28)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:67)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:61)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureOutputsAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureOutputsAfterExecutionStep.java:69)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureOutputsAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureOutputsAfterExecutionStep.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.executeWithoutCache(BuildCacheStep.java:189)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.executeAndStoreInCache(BuildCacheStep.java:145)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.lambda$executeWithCache$4(BuildCacheStep.java:101)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.lambda$executeWithCache$5(BuildCacheStep.java:101)
        at org.gradle.internal.Try$Success.map(Try.java:175)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.executeWithCache(BuildCacheStep.java:85)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.lambda$execute$0(BuildCacheStep.java:74)
        at org.gradle.internal.Either$Left.fold(Either.java:115)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.caching.CachingState.fold(CachingState.java:62)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:73)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipUpToDateStep.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:27)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveIncrementalCachingStateStep.executeDelegate(ResolveIncrementalCachingStateStep.java:49)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveIncrementalCachingStateStep.executeDelegate(ResolveIncrementalCachingStateStep.java:27)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AbstractResolveCachingStateStep.execute(AbstractResolveCachingStateStep.java:71)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AbstractResolveCachingStateStep.execute(AbstractResolveCachingStateStep.java:39)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:65)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:105)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AbstractCaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(AbstractCaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AbstractCaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(AbstractCaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AbstractSkipEmptyWorkStep.executeWithNonEmptySources(AbstractSkipEmptyWorkStep.java:125)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AbstractSkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(AbstractSkipEmptyWorkStep.java:56)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AbstractSkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(AbstractSkipEmptyWorkStep.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:23)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.HandleStaleOutputsStep.execute(HandleStaleOutputsStep.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.HandleStaleOutputsStep.execute(HandleStaleOutputsStep.java:41)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignMutableWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignMutableWorkspaceStep.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$4.withWorkspace(TaskExecution.java:289)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignMutableWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignMutableWorkspaceStep.java:31)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignMutableWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignMutableWorkspaceStep.java:22)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ChoosePipelineStep.execute(ChoosePipelineStep.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ChoosePipelineStep.execute(ChoosePipelineStep.java:23)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.lambda$execute$2(ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.java:67)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.execute(ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.java:67)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.execute(ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.java:39)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:34)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultExecutionEngine$1.execute(DefaultExecutionEngine.java:61)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:127)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:116)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:74)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:209)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:166)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:42)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:331)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:318)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.lambda$execute$0(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:314)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.CurrentBuildOperationRef.with(CurrentBuildOperationRef.java:85)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:314)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:303)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:459)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:376)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:48)


Reported as https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/30679
